# Cant get my Camry to accept the new FOB

Tags: toyota, keyless-entry

I have a 2006 Toyota Camry.  I have a new FOB and have followed all the steps to go into programming mode no problem but at the very end the locks cycle through twice showing that the FOB hasn't been accepted.   Its the same serial # as the original FOB and the funny thing is I thought the original one was broken but I can do the same with that one to and at the very end it cycles through locking twice. I can't get it to except the FOB what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found for your 06 Camry, I assume you should use the Add Mode.

[image]

**More detail on modes below**

After B step 5 see image 1 below

After B step 7 see image 2 below

After C step 2 see image 3 below

[image]

.
**Image 1**
[image: Image 1]

.

**Image 2**
[image]

.

**Image 3**
[image]